# Solving a 5 dimensional function in a neighbourhood

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^5 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by

$$f(u,v,w,x,y)=(uy+vx+w+x^2,uvw+x+y+1)$$

such that $f(2,1,0,-1,0)=(0,0)$

(i) Show that we can solve $f(u,v,w,x,y) = (0,0)$ for $(x,y)$ in terms of (u,v,w) in a neighbourhood of $(2,1,0)$.

(ii)If $(x,y) = \phi(u,v,w)$ is the solution for (i) then show that derivative of $\phi$ at $(2,1,0)$ is

$$D\phi(2,1,0)=\frac13
\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & -1 & -3 \\
        0 & 1 & -3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

**Here's how I tried:**

Let $F=uy+vx+w+x^2=0$

& $G=uvw+x+y+1=0$

$$\frac{\partial(F,G)}{\partial(x,y)}_{(2,1,0,-1,0)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
        v+2x & u \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\qquad \qquad \qquad=
\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & 2 \\
        1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

which is non singular, so solution exists.

Part (ii):

we can write

$$x=X(u,v,w)$$

$$y=Y(u,v,w)$$

defined in the neighbourhood of $(2,1,0)$

such that:
$$X(2,1,0)=-1$$

$$Y(2,1,0)=0$$

what to do next? How to find $x=X(u,v,w)$ & $y=Y(u,v,w)$?

Comment: This is a routine implicit function theorem problem. Where do you get stuck? If you have Rudin's book, the statement of the implicit function theorem there tells you exactly how to do parts (i) and (ii).

Comment: I have read IFT but I am having hard time applying it. Can you give me some link where I can find solved examples related to it.

Comment: @HenryT.Horton I have added in my original text how I tried this problem. Please tell me how to proceed further. Thanx

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I wasn't around much in the past day and a half. I've posted a simple solution for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution need not be nearly as complicated as what izœc does.

To show that $\phi$ exists in a neighborhood of $(2,1,0)$, we do exactly as you did:
$$Df(u,v,w,x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} y & x & 1 & v + 2x & u \\ vw & uw & uv & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
$$Df(2,1,0,-1,0) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Since the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
corresponding to $(x,y)$ is invertible, the implicit function theorem can be applied.

Now if we write $Df = (A | B)$, where
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}, \quad B = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},$$
a little work with the chain rule shows us that
$$D\phi(2,1,0) = -A^{-1} B.$$
This works for all implicit function theorem problems; see Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* for the details. In our case,
$$A^{-1} = -\frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix},$$
and hence
\begin{align}
D\phi(2,1,0) & = \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -2 \\\ -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \\
 & = \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & -3 \\ 0 & 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix}. 
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: Typos have been removed, and the correct answer was obtained.

From the Implicit Function Theorem, we have that where 
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} \\
\end{array}
\right|_{(u,v,w,x,y) = (2,1,0,-1,0)}
=
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
v+2x & u \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right| _{(u,v,w,x,y) = (2,1,0,-1,0)}
\neq 0
$$
We can solve for $m$ of the variables of $f$ in terms of $n-m$ other variables (here, $n=5:u,v,w,x,y$ and $m=2:x,y$) about some neighborhood of $(u,v,w) = (2,1,0)$.
So, as
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
v+2x & u \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right| _{(u,v,w,x,y) = (2,1,0,-1,0)}
=
(1-2)(-2) 
= 2
\neq 0
$$ 
Then, there is a neighborhood $U$ about $(u,v,w) = (2,1,0)$ where we can solve for $f(\mathbf{x}) = f(u,v,w,\phi(u,v,w)) = 0$.

Note, that we can find the general set of values $(u,v,w)$ about which you can do this by considering 
$$
\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
v+2x & u \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right| _{(u,v,w,x,y) = (u,v,w,-1,0)}
=
(v-2)(-u) 
\neq 0
$$
implies that $ \left\{ (u,v,w) : v \neq 2 \right\} \cup \left\{ (u,v,w) : u \neq 0 \right\} $ is the complete set.

Irregardless, to find $\phi$, let 
$$
\begin{cases}
uy + vx + w +x^2 &= 0 \\
uvw + x+ y + 1 &= 0
\end{cases} 
$$
This can be solved in any manner - for instance, 
$$
y = -1 -x -uvw \implies x^2 + (v-u)x + (w-u-u^2vw) = 0
$$
so $x = \frac{u-v}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }}{2}$. Then, $y= -1 -\frac{u-v}{2} \mp \frac{\sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }}{2} - uvw$.
Therefore, 
\begin{align}
\phi(u,v,w) &= (x(u,v,w), y(u,v,w)) \\
&= \left( \frac{u-v}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }}{2}, (-1) \left( 1 + \frac{u-v}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }}{2} + uvw \right) \right)
\end{align}
We may take the sign $\pm$ to be either $+$ or $-$ (I worked it out for $-$). To check, $D \phi (2,10)$ is 
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{cccc}
\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial w} \\
\frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial u} & \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial \phi_2}{\partial w} \\\end{array}
\right) _{\mathbf{u} = (u,v,w) = (2,1,0)}
$$
That is,
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{( -2(v-u) + 4(1+2uvw) )}{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} & - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2(v-u) + 4u^2w }{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} & (-1) \frac{-4(1 - u^2v)}{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} \\
%
- \frac{1}{2} + \frac{( -2(v-u) + 4(1+2uvw) )}{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} - vw & \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2(v-u) + 4u^2w }{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} - uw & - uv + \frac{-4(1 - u^2v)}{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} \\
\end{array}
\right) _{\mathbf{u}}
%
$$
or as below in the transpose form (rewritten to fit on the page)
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{( -2(v-u) + 4(1+2uvw) )}{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} & - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{( -2(v-u) + 4(1+2uvw) )}{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} - vw  \\
%
- \frac{1}{2} - \frac{2(v-u) + 4u^2w }{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} & \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2(v-u) + 4u^2w }{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} - uw \\
%
(-1) \frac{-4(1 - u^2v)}{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }} & - uv + \frac{-4(1 - u^2v)}{4 \sqrt{ (v-u)^2 - 4(w-u-u^2vw) }}
\end{array}
\right) _{\mathbf{u}} ^\mathbf{T}
%
$$

So, we have
$$
%
D \phi (2,1,0)
= 
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & - \tfrac{1}{3}  & - 1 \\
0 & \tfrac{1}{3}  & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\frac{1}{3}
\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & - 1  & -3 \\
0 & 1  & -3 \\
\end{array}
\right] .
$$

Comment: Thank you so much..
I just wish there was a method which was computationally less cumbersome.

Comment: You're welcome. I agree, it would be nice; unfortunately, there is none that I am familiar with.. the Implicit Function Theorem is nonconstructive with regards to solving for an implicit function about a neighborhood, and I don't know of a general method that can be used to explicitly solve it, much less one that is computationally elegant.

Comment: @Mathy, it is very easy to use Mathematica to do cumbersome computations.